# Type mismatch error on multicell entry in Workseet_SelectionChange

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I want to call a macro if the value of any cell in that column is "T", but every time there will be a **run-time error: Type Mismatch** for the line of `If Target.Value = "T" Then`. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Target.Column = 36 Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If Target.Value = "T" Then
            Range("AJ" & ThisRow).Select
            Call mail_outlook
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can just do `If Target.Column = 36 And Target.Value = "T" Then`

Comment: Do you need to be able to handle multiple updates to Col 36 (eg if a user drag-fills in that column or enters into multiple cells at once using Ctrl+Enter)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a cell that has an error in it... You can check for that condition like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not IsError(Target) Then
     If Target.Column = 36 Then ' AJ
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If Target.Value = "T" Then
            Range("AJ" & ThisRow).Select
            Call mail_outlook
        End If
     End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Also, you can check `Target` to see if the selection is more than one cell (if that helps)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
     If Target.Column = 36 Then ' AJ
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If Target.Value = "T" Then
            Range("AJ" & ThisRow).Select
            Call mail_outlook
        End If
     End If
  End If
End Sub
```